# Android: How to configure kernel?

Tags: android, kernel, android-source

I'm following steps at this website, http://bootloader.wikidot.com/android:kgdb, and one of the steps requires me to configure the kernel when I make it. I was wondering how to do this? What files do I need to edit, or what commands do I need to input?

Comment: Is there a reason you need KGDB if you've apparently never compiled a kernel before?

Comment: I have compiled the kernel before, but I have never tried to change some of the configurations

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a very trivial change you can open the .config file in the kernel source directory with a text editor and do it manually.

For a change where options depend on each other its better to use one of the provided interfaces, such as 'make menuconfig'

You will find lots of documentation on this online, which makes the question a little surprising